# How to say - Soccer Nutmeg

Tags: sports

Recently I have been watching the World Cup, I wanted to know how to say Nutmeg (as in kicking it through the other players legs) in Japanese. I figure it's not ナツメグ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was in the dictionary - but it's like the 100th entry. I had to scroll down really far. To express the idea of a nutmeg you say 股抜{またぬ}き.

The Kanji 股 means "the leg from the knee up" and　抜く means... well There a lot of uses of this word. It basically means "to remove from". It makes sense to use it here, but not if I try to define it in my own words. If you are curious check this out https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/169219/meaning/m0u/

Comment: `The answer was in the dictionary - but it's like the 100th entry. I had to scroll down really far. `  -- 「サッカー　nutmeg」でググったらすぐ見つかります→https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=URIWWpvkNMHz8QXoxb8Y&btnG=Search&q=サッカー+nutmeg&oq=AP+スタイル%E3%80%80リンク&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10892.12635.0.19575.5.3.0.0.0.0.494.585.1j4-1.2.0....0...1c.1j4.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.7mkBp0Wcs0g